# Image of a straight line under $f(z)=\frac{1}{2} (z+\frac{1}{z})$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

> What is $f(\{t\eta : t \in (0,1]\})$ for every $\eta \in \partial\mathbb{D} $ and $f(z)=\frac{1}{2} (z+\frac{1}{z})$. Where $\mathbb{D}$ is the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$.

I've plugged in $z=e^{i\phi}$:

$f(te^{i\phi})=\frac{1}{2}[cos(\phi)(t+\frac{1}{t})+isin(\phi)(t-\frac{1}{t})]$

For a fixed $t$ this is a point on an ellipse in $\mathbb{C}$ since for $a=\frac{1}{2}(t+\frac{1}{t})$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}(t-\frac{1}{t})$ the equation of an ellipse $\frac{Re(f(te^{i\phi}))^2}{a^2}+\frac{Im(f(te^{i\phi}))^2}{b^2}=1$ is true (for $t\neq1$).

The focuspoints (for all $t\neq1$) of the ellipse are $\pm 1$. But changing $t$ means changing the size of the ellipse. I have put $f(\{t\eta : t \in [0,1]\})$ into Geogebra to see how the lines look for different $\phi$ (between $0$ and $\pi/2$). However, I dont know any way to describe the trace of the points (sadly Geogebra only traces the point $f(t\eta )$ for $t$ going stepwise from $0$ to $1$).[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $\eta$, the track $\{f(t\eta)\colon t\in(0,1]\}$ is part of a hyperbola (on either the upper half plane or the lower half plane, depending on $\eta$) unless $\eta=\pm 1$.  The easiest way to see this is to use
$$
\left(t+\frac1t\right)^2-\left(t-\frac1t\right)^2=4
$$
so
$$
\frac{x^2}{\cos^2\phi}-\frac{y^2}{\sin^2\phi}=1.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know the equations for ellipses and hyperbola are this similar.